# Execute Node.JS terminal commands in a function

Tags: node.js

I have a Node.JS file and usually I run it with the terminal command `node index.js`, but I want to automate it. How would I be able to run that command in a function instead of the terminal?

Comment: You want to automate how? Like recurring or something like a bash function? Please clarify, what OS you're using etc

Comment: @Phix Pretty much recurring. I just want to run a Javascript file once every 15 minutes (lets say)
Just to clarify, I'm using Windows and Command Prompt Terminal to run it manually (at this point)

Comment: There's cron tasks, and whatever the equivalent in windows is.